# Best way to copy millions of files from S3 to GCS?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I am searching for a way to move a very large number of files (over 10 million) from an S3 bucket over to Google Cloud Storage but so far am having issues.

Currently I am using gsutil because it has native support for communicating between both S3 and GCS but I am getting less than great performance.  Maybe I am just doing things wrong but I have been using the following gsutil command:

```
gsutil -m cp -R s3://bucket gs://bucket
```

I spun up a c3.2xlarge AWS instance (16GB 8CPU) so that I could have enough horse power but it doesn't appear that the box is getting any better throughput than a 2GB 2CPU box, I don't get it?

I have been messing around with the `~/.boto` config file and currently have the following options set:

```
parallel_process_count = 8
parallel_thread_count = 100
```

I thought for sure increasing the thread count by a factor of 10x would help but from my testing so far hasn't made a difference.  Is there anything else that can be done to boost performance?

Or is there maybe a better tool for moving S3 data to GCS?  I am looking at the SDK's and am half way tempted to write something in Java.

Comment: What is the (approximate) total size of the data that you're moving?  And what is the performance (files per second) that you're seeing? That you get the same performance even with fewer CPUs and more threads implies you're limited on bandwidth.  Depending on how the data is distributed, you could partition the copy by prefix and use multiple VMs running gsutil to sped this up.

Comment: @TravisHobrla There is about 800GB of data, I'm not sure how to check the performance?  I was hoping bandwidth would not be an issue since this was going from an EC2 server to Google but I will definitely check network saturation.

Comment: You might be interested in signing up for [Online Cloud Import](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/online-cloud-import)

Comment: For data of that size, gsutil is probably easier than the Online Cloud Import.  To test performance you could copy a small subset of the files.  Are the files distributed across any prefixes that you could partition by?  Then you could use multiple instances to speed it up.

Comment: @TravisHobrla I could partiiton it up a little bit, but it will be ugly.  I found this tool works great for S3 - https://github.com/cobbzilla/s3s3mirror.  I wonder if I could adapt it to GCS?

Comment: @TravisHobrla Looks like my bandwidth is a little all over the place - right now it's hanging around 10-15 Mbit/s both in and out but it has been up around 20 as well.

Comment: If your goal is to mirror the content, I recommend using gsutil rsync instead of cp.  Regardless, the performance will be similar.  I doubt you would gain much performance by adapting s3s3mirror; copying within S3 or GCS tends to be much faster than copying across them.  At 10MBit/s it will take just over 7 days to copy your data by my count.  If you can partition the data even 4 ways you can get this done with gsutil in a couple days.

Comment: @TravisHobrla I had very good results with s3s3mirror for bucket to bucket copy within AWS but yes it is much different to move across a provider.  Thanks for the tip on the rsync - I think I will use that and chunk up the directories to sync across multiple servers.

Comment: After you complete your initial copy, running rsync on the entire bucket should be extremely fast as it just operates on the diffs in file listings.

Comment: @TravisHobrla thanks for the insight.  One last thing, how long would you expect something like this to take to complete the initial sync, given the information so far?

Comment: You're copying 800GB at 10Mbit/s, which is about 7 days as I mentioned above.  So the initial copy will be 7 days divided by the number of partitions, assuming you can partition evenly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google Cloud Storage Online Cloud Import](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/online-cloud-import) was built specifically to import large sizes and number of files to GCS from either a large list of URLs or from an S3 bucket.  It was designed for data sizes that would take too long using "gsutil -m" (which was a good thing to try first).  It is currently free to use.

(Disclaimer, I am the PM for the project)

Comment: I will take a look and get signed up, thanks.  What is going on under the hood if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I'll check with the powers that be and find out how much of the "how" can be shared.  In the meantime, an [IO 2013 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGofZI66oSE) highlights some related thinking.

Comment: marvelous tool, really fast

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to copy files the other way GCS -> S3? Our jobs run on GCP, but customer needs them on S3. Would have to move the jobs to AWS as well...